# SQLite tables design for Android devices

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm curious if relation table from M:M relation is needed in my case.
The structure looks like this:

Table `Records` with fields: `id`, `name`, `tags` (as a string).

Table `Tags` with fields: `id`, `tagName`. As you see it's quite simple.

One `Record` could contain several `Tags`. On the other hand one `Tag` could belong to the few `Records`.

The case is adding/removing/modifying `Records`. So do I really need here some 'between' table with `tag_id` and `record_id`? Since `Tags` table is quite small. May be it will be better to store relation only on `Tags` table side?

I assume that there could be something between 50k - 150k records in `Tags` table.
What do you think about performance of such solution? DB size will be bigger - that's known fact.
DB is SQLite on Android 8+ devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always recommend that you use an in between table when handling many to many relationships with databases. It will prevent data duplication from occurring in the other tables, which is definitely something you should prioritize since it seems you will have quite a lot of data in your database.

If you haven't learned about it yet, read up on [database normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: Thanks! I heard about it. But it will be definitely good idea to read article and watch the video

Answer (score 1):

What the use case? Android databases are not made to be storing excessively large amounts of data.

It would probably make more sense to store this externally and have the android device perform SQL queries.

In terms of Foreign keys for Tags / Records, it depends on the use case. If I understand correctly you could just use tagID as a foreign key in Records, but again it depends on the use case.

Comment: User will add records with some amount of tags. Tags in different records could be the same. Then I will need for example check how many times selected tag was used.
In this project I have no opportunity to store DB externally